# Conditional JOIN with wildcard override

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to do the following:

- Join on a tableA based on an IDa and return results from table WHERE tableA.ClientID = @clientId

This is working fine however I know want to add a 'wildcard' value as say that if `@clientId` is 1, return everything from tableP.

I currently have the following:

```
// @clientId is a parameter passed into the stored procedure

SELECT *
FROM tableP tp
LEFT JOIN tableA ta ON ta.IDa = tp.IDa
WHERE ta.ClientID = @clientId
```

Like I said, the above works fine but I want to add a 'wildcard' value and say if 1, then skip the `LEFT JOIN` per se and just return everything from `tableP` regardless of if it exists in `tableA` or not.

I tried changing the `LEFT JOIN` to the following:

```
LEFT JOIN tableA ta ON ta.IDa = tp.IDa AND @clientId <> 1
```

However this doesn't return anything.

EDIT: I am selecting `*` as this is not production code, I am debugging.

Comment: may not be the best solution, but do a union with your second condition

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name tag added. It's sql server FYI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `left join` doesn't make sense.  The `where` clause is turning it into an inner join.

I think you just want:

```
SELECT *
FROM tableA ta LEFT JOIN
     tableP tp
     ON ta.IDa = tp.IDa
WHERE ta.ClientID = @clientId or @clientId = 1;
```

Note that you should not be using `SELECT *` for production code.  You should list out the columns that you want -- and take care of duplicates such as `IDa` in the result set.

Comment: In regards to the above, how does this solve the issue of the 'wildcard' value?

Comment: That part was accidentally left out. You would need to add "or @clientId = 1" to the where clause. TBH a wildcard value of 1 seems very suspicious. Typically I see NULL interpreted as "include everything".

Comment: @Smor It's in regards to a certain client. Client 1 should be able to see everything regardless of checks. Adding the `OR` check against `@clientId = 1` like stated solved this question.

Answer (score 1):

Conditional:

```
IF @clientId = 1 THEN
BEGIN
  SELECT *
  FROM tableP tp
END ELSE BEGIN
  SELECT *
  FROM tableP tp
  LEFT JOIN tableA ta ON ta.IDa = tp.IDa
  WHERE ta.ClientID = @clientId
END
```

If you want have same columns, you must add it manually. But as I see it isn't production code because you use *

Answer (score 1):

You can conditionally execute where condition using COALESCE function. When you want everything without considering where condition, pass null value for @clientId variable. The following code will work fine

```
SELECT *
FROM tableA ta LEFT JOIN
     tableP tp
     ON ta.IDa = tp.IDa
WHERE ta.ClientID =COALESCE(@clientId,ta.ClientID);
```